# How to print literal unicode string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, character, unicode-literals

I have an array containing strings with special unicode characters:

```
var a = [
    ["a", 33],  
    ["h\u016B", 44],
    ["s\u00EF", 51],
    ...
];
```

When I loop over this array:

```
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    document.write(a[i][0] + "<br />");
}
```

It prints characters with accents:

```
a
hù
sô
...
```

and I want:

```
a
h\u016B
s\u00EF
...
```

How can I achieve this in Javascript?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like this?

```
/* Creates a uppercase hex number with at least length digits from a given number */
function fixedHex(number, length){
    var str = number.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while(str.length < length)
        str = "0" + str;
    return str;
}

/* Creates a unicode literal based on the string */    
function unicodeLiteral(str){
    var i;
    var result = "";
    for( i = 0; i < str.length; ++i){
        /* You should probably replace this by an isASCII test */
        if(str.charCodeAt(i) > 126 || str.charCodeAt(i) < 32)
            result += "\\u" + fixedHex(str.charCodeAt(i),4);
        else
            result += str[i];
    }

    return result;
}

var a = [
    ["a", 33],  
    ["h\u016B", 44],
    ["s\u00EF", 51]
];

var i;
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    document.write(unicodeLiteral(a[i][0]) + "<br />");
}
```

#### Result

```
a
h\u016B
s\u00EF
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3Szv/1/)

Comment: Good solution but I think it should be `if(str.charCodeAt(i) > 127)` (ASCII stops at 0x7F).

Comment: @dda: Doh, indeed. However `0x7F` is DEL, so `0x7E` should be a better upper bound. Edited my answer, thanks for the remark :).

Comment: This will not display unicode like \u0050 (which is a valid ascii character) . How to handle that ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 Which wasn't intended in the original question. Remove the `if`. Note that `'\u0050'` and `"P"` have the same representation; you cannot check whether `"P"` was originally `'\u0050'`.

Comment: @Zeta if i remove the if, it will convert everything to unicode

Comment: @gaurav5430: Yup. Again, there is ___no___ difference between `"\u0050"` and `"P"` after the browser has parsed your code (or any other string for that matter). You either display ASCII as is, or you display ASCII as unicode. There's no inbetween.

Comment: yeah... actually my requirement depends on the position and offset of a string token in the actual string and the displayed string, which gets messed up because of this

Answer (score 7):

javascript's `string.charCodeAt()` should help.  I.e.

`"test".charCodeAt(0)` will return the numeric code for `"t"`.

Beyond that, you'd need to write an if statement to check if the character is non-ASCII, etc.

Answer (score 7):

if you have a unicode char and you want it as a string you can do this

```
x = "h\u016B";
// here the unicode is the second char
uniChar = x.charCodeAt(1).toString(16); // 16b
uniChar = uniChar.toUpperCase(); // it is now 16B
uniChar = "\\u0" + uniChar; // it is now \\u016B
x = x.charAt(0) + uniChar; // x = "h\\u016B" which prints as you wish
```

Answer (score 7):

So, gotten here tried to answer this question: [Javascript: display unicode as it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474425/javascript-display-unicode-as-is#35474425) but it has been closed because of this question here.

Just another answer for this problem: 
It is also possible (at least in some modern browsers) to use the [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) - function

Syntax is like this:

```
var rawStr = String.raw`Hello \u0153`;
```

Here is a working fiddle (Chrome, FF): http://jsfiddle.net/w9L6qgt6/1/