# Javascript: display unicode as it is

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have a string like :

```
var a = " Hello \u0153 "
```

when I `console.log(a)` I get

```
" Hello œ"
```

What I want is to have `" Hello \u0153 "`

I know if I can convert the string to `" Hello \\u0153 "` I will get what I want, but I am not able to convert the single slash to double slash, because anytime I try to perform any string functions, they are performed on `" Hello œ "`

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24044/)

I have looked at the question : [How to print literal unicode string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937225/how-to-print-literal-unicode-string-in-javascript)

but the accepted answer does not work for strings which have ASCII characters written as Unicode , for example it will display `\u0050` as `P` instead of `\u0050` also, it will convert characters like œ to their unicode values, although it does not appear as such in the source string.

Comment: What you're trying to do is impossible. The string doesn't "remember" which characters were given to it as Unicode values.

Comment: @Juhana yeah, i get your point, but i was wondering if there was some way to get the raw string or the unprocessed value.

Comment: There isn't any way.